# define array variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How to define variable inside array without key? This doesnt working and I dont know how...

```
$array = array("list" => array());

$list = $array["list"][] = array("sub_list" = array());
$list["sub_list"][] = "text1";
$list["sub_list"][] = "text2";
$list["sub_list"][] = "text2";

$list2 = $array["list"][] = array("sub_list" = array());
$list2["sub_list"][] = "text1";
$list2["sub_list"][] = "text2";
$list2["sub_list"][] = "text3";
```

Needed result:

```
$array = array(
   "list" => array(
      array(
        "sub_list" = array("text1", "text2", "text3")
      ),
      array(
        "sub_list" = array("text1", "text2", "text3")
      )
    )
);
```

It's not used in loop or for/foreach!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to declare the array using the second method?

Comment: There is a typo `"sub_list" = array()` it should be `=>`

Comment: @Dharman my mistake, ofc with ```=>``` but same problem - ```sub_list``` are always empty arrays

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you rephrase the problem, please?

Comment: @NigelRen second method?

Comment: @waterloomatt like ```$array["list"][]["sub_list"]``` simply add something to exists array without last key ```$array["list"][``` HERE ```]["sub_list"]``` or look to last post - Im create new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'list' => []
];

$list = [];
$list[] = 'text1';
$list[] = 'text2';
$list[] = 'text3';
$array['list'][]['sub_list'] = $list;

$array['list'][]['sub_list'] = $list;

$list = [];
$list[] = 'text4';
$list[] = 'text5';
$list[] = 'text6';
$array['list'][]['sub_list'] = $list;
```

And you will have :

```
$array = array(
   "list" => array(
      array(
        "sub_list" => array("text1", "text2", "text3")
      ),
      array(
        "sub_list" => array("text1", "text2", "text3")
      ),
      array(
        "sub_list" => array("text4", "text5", "text6")
      )
    )
);
```

Comment: code working as I wrote, but impossible add something to exists array with ```$array['list'][]["SOMETHING_NEXT"]``` is created new array, show my request below... thanks

Comment: I don't know how your script work or need to work only with your question. So you need to store the index when you create a new list array. Then you can use the index to add something like `$array['list'][0]['SOMETHING_NEXT']` as same deep as `sub_list`

Comment: I think something like ```$var = $array['list'][]``` but its maybe impossible, okay... index ```$i++;``` and ```$array['list'][ $i ]['SOMETHING_NEXT']``` how to identify key

Answer (score 0):

```
$array["list"][] = array("sub_list" => array());
$list= [];
$list[] = array("text1", "text2", "text3");
$list[] = array("text1", "text2", "text3");
$array["list"][]["sub_list"] = $list;
```

althought it's array inside array and this array is also in array

i need `$array["list"][]` as variable, when is called `$array["list"][]["sub_list"] = $list;` is created new one array, i need add `"sub_list"` to first array